# Error in if ((!is.matrix(model)) | ncol(model) != 3) stop("model argument must be a 3-column matrix")

Tags: r

I'm learning R from scratch and attempting to test for mediating effect with the following code:

```
NQ21 <- as.numeric (as.factor(DB$Q21))

ModelA <- 
'NQ21 ~ a*OCBI
CAC ~ b*NQ21
CAC ~ cp*OCBI
ab:=a*b
total := cp + ab'

fsem1 <- sem(ModelA, data = DB)
summary(fsem1, standardized = TRUE)
```

Got an error instead:

```
Error in if ((!is.matrix(model)) | ncol(model) != 3) stop("model argument must be a 3-column matrix") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Change the first line to `DB$NQ21 <- as.numeric (as.factor(DB$Q21))`

Comment: change the first line. but the error persist.

Comment: Then please provide example data so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a guess on your error. You are calling `sem` from the package `sem` instead of `lavaan`. If I use an example data.frame like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
DB <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100),ncol=5))
colnames(DB) = c("OCBI","CAC","a","b","cp")
DB$Q21 = rep(paste0("Q",1:4),5)
DB$NQ21 = as.numeric(factor(DB$Q21))

ModelA <- 
'NQ21 ~ a*OCBI
CAC ~ b*NQ21
CAC ~ cp*OCBI
ab:=a*b
total := cp + ab'
```

Using `sem::sem`, I get the same error:

```
library(sem)
sem(ModelA, data = DB)
Error in if ((!is.matrix(model)) | ncol(model) != 3) stop("model argument must be a 3-column matrix") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

We unload the package `sem` and load `lavaan`:

```
detach("package:sem",unload=TRUE)
library(lavaan)
sem(ModelA, data = DB)

lavaan 0.6-6 ended normally after 21 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of free parameters                          5
                                                      
  Number of observations                            20
                                                      
Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                 0.000
  Degrees of freedom                                 0
```